Vite Proxy 'with options' doesn't work. 'string shorthand' works
My vite config, proxy, doesn't seem to be working.
From the docs, https://vite.dev/config/server-options#server-proxy, there are multiple ways you can write the proxy setup.
The below is taken directly from vite docs,
The issue
When I use "string shorthand", my request can be forwarded to localhost:8080
when I use "with options" version, my proxy doesn't work.
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      // string shorthand: http://localhost:5173/foo -> http://localhost:4567/foo
      '/foo': 'http://localhost:4567',
      // with options: http://localhost:5173/api/bar-> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/bar
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
      // with RegExp: http://localhost:5173/fallback/ -> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
      '^/fallback/.*': {
        target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/fallback/, ''),
      },
      // Using the proxy instance
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          // proxy will be an instance of 'http-proxy'
        },
      },
      // Proxying websockets or socket.io: ws://localhost:5173/socket.io -> ws://localhost:5174/socket.io
      // Exercise caution using `rewriteWsOrigin` as it can leave the proxying open to CSRF attacks.
      '/socket.io': {
        target: 'ws://localhost:5174',
        ws: true,
        rewriteWsOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
})

This is my current vite config setup, ints vite.config.ts file, not sure if the typescript file makes a difference in this situation.
export default defineConfig({

  server: {
    proxy: {
      // '/api/': `http://localhost:8080`,
      '^/api/': {
        target: `http://localhost:8080`,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
      },
      '^/api/json-api/.*': {
        target: `http://localhost:${process.env.JSON_API_PORT || 5003}`,
        rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api\/json-api/, ''),
      },
      '/api/validator/.*': {
        target: `http://localhost:${process.env.SCAN_PROXY_API_PORT || 9000}`,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});

So you can see I've commented out the string shorthand. So with the version with options, it DOESN"T work, the other proxies listed in there don't get hit as well.
However when I just use '/api':'http://localhost:8080', the proxy works, any ideas?
